# Is there simple way to create UIColor extension for enum of UIColor with String raw data in Swift 3?

Tags: enums, swift3, uicolor

I would like to create a simple extension to UIColor such that I could do something like this:

```
extension UIColor {
    enum colorString: String  {

        ....
    }
}


let array: [UIColor.colorString] = [ .red, .green, .blue]

let color: UIColor = array[1]

let text: String = array[1].rawValue
```

But I'm having trouble to make the extension part working. I've tried multiple attempts but not successful.  I might have missed something. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: So what's your issue?

Comment: I was unsuccessful in creating the content of the extension.  Represented as   '....'  above.

Comment: Unsuccessful how?

Comment: So basically I thought, I could make the enum value to represent the UIColor value. (as the usage example shown above). But the XCode / Swift compiler won't allow me to do that.

Comment: "won't allow me to do that" What does this mean? Dude, do you expect me to guess what your code is, and what the issue is?

Comment: Actually, the title completely lacks any relevance to the issue you're having: you already had `    enum colorString: String  { ... }`, and almost certainly you tried something like `case red, case blue...` in the `...` section. It was the initializer you were missing that uses the enum to obtain a colour.

Comment: As a stack overflow policy, we like to see what people have tried. Not only does it give us a better understanding of the question, but it also sets apart the question from all the other "do my work for me" shitposts that we get an on hourly basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this. Depends on how many colors you want to do this for. Not sure what you intend to do with this but it doesn't look like the most useful extension.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(_ colorString: ColorString) {
        switch colorString {
        case .red:
            self.init(red:1.0, green:0.0, blue:0.0, alpha:1.0)
        case .green:
            self.init(red:0.0, green:1.0, blue:0.0, alpha:1.0)
        case .blue:
            self.init(red:0.0, green:0.0, blue:1.0, alpha:1.0)
        }
    }
    enum ColorString: String  {
        case red
        case green
        case blue
    }
}
```

Your conversion from colorString to UIColor would have to be of the form

```
let color = UIColor(array[1])
```